# TFS API Json Documentation

Tags: json, api, tfs

I use the the TFS Builds in my application and was wondering if there is a documentary for the json response which i get from the TFS API. Especially for the field "AuthoredBy".

[Here an example of the response json.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it0QV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is documentation (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/build/contracts/builddefinitionreference) but it is not kept up to date, is incomplete and wrong on many instances unfortunately :(

Edit: i noticed the link i posted at that time now forwards to a different api... here is the updated link -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0